# jQuery Code to filter multiple attributes

Tags: html, jquery, forms

## What I want to do

As you can see in code section, created html code shows one form and one table. In the table, there are many records with button whose name is 'copy'. Once this button clicked, corresponding data set is copied to the form. Here I use jQuery. Please read Error section to understand what I am  wondering after having look at the code.

## Environment

- Windows11 64bit
- Python v3.10.10
- jQuery v3.6.4
- Google Chrome latest version

## Code

```
import sqlite3
import webbrowser

conn = sqlite3.connect("hoge.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,item TEXT,shopname TEXT)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()

BASE_HTML="""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ja'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>DEMO</title>
    <script src='path_to_jquery_file' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <caption>FORM</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td>
        <td>shopname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' id='input_item' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='input_shopname' value=''></td>
    </tr>
</table>"""

idx = [1,2,3,4]
conn = sqlite3.connect("hoge.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

BASE_HTML+="""<table>
    <caption>RECORD LIST</caption>"""

for i in idx:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM buffer WHERE id="+str(i))
    res = cur.fetchone()

    buf_item = res[1]
    buf_shopname = res[2]
    
    BASE_HTML+="""
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' class='buf_item' name='"""+str(i)+"""' value='"""+buf_item+"""'></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='buf_shopname' name='"""+str(i)+"""' value='"""+buf_shopname+"""'></td>
        <td><button class='copy_from_list' type='button' value='"""+str(i)+"""'>COPY</button></td>
    </tr>"""

BASE_HTML+="</table>"

BASE_HTML+="""
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".copy_from_list").click(function(){
        let number = $(this).val();
        
        let copy_item = $(".buf_item input[name=number]").val();
        $("#input_item").val(copy_item);
        
        let copy_shopname = $(".buf_shopname input[name=number]").val();
        $("#input_shopname").val(copy_shopname);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
"""

with open("test.html",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(BASE_HTML)
webbrowser.open("test.html")
```

## Error

There are many records listed in the table, so I use multiple selection of selectors to focus on one record. There are classes whose name is 'buf_item'/'buf_shopname'. But these class attribute is set in each record, so I use name attribute which contains record id. So that I can focus on one record. I confirmed that following format is valid in jQuery to multiple selection of selector:

> let copy_item = $(".buf_item input[name=number]").val();

In the console in the browser, 'undefined' is shown, which means this style of description is incorrect. How should I describe jQuery code to realize what I want to do ? I am waiting for your advice and comments. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: It should be  `let copy_item = $("input.buf_item[name='"+number+"']").val();`

Comment: Thanks for your advise, callback. Please let me know why you use '+' sign to sandwich variable ? In addition, Please let me know " sign also. Please let me know the reference site to understand this knowledge.

Comment: `+` concatenates strings.  `"` as in `"this is a string"` designates a string.   As you already have in your code.

Comment: `".buf_item input[name=number]"` is a constant string - the `number` part is just part of the string, to use the variable you need to use a variable.

Comment: `[name='value']` - the `'` (not `"`) is the same as `"` but inside an existing `"`.   This ensure the value is treated as a whole and not interpreted.    eg `var val="]"` would generate a selector as `$("[name=]]")` which would then fail.  So put the attribute value in quotes:  `$("[name=']']`)` and it will match `<div name="]">`.  While a derived example, this can cause problems with spaces/=/" and other characters in "value"

Comment: Thank you for your advise, freedomn-m. I understand what you explained. I feel I can build up codes !!